# Add HTTP Interceptor to standAlone component

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to add an interceptor to standalone component by adding the interceptor to the `providers` array in the component itself (  `{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }` ), but it's not working...

here is a link to [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p9qqnu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth.interceptor.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild-stand-alone.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fparent-stand-alone.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdemo.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

thanks :)

Comment: Did you try it in main.ts? Http interceptors work application wide.

Comment: I’d expect this to work..? Can you report back once you found a working solution please?

Comment: like this - `platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule, {providers: [
      { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useExisting: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    ]})`? it steal not working

Comment: I think this behavior is not supported yet by angular. Related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18894 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19852. You need to put you interceptor at the application NgModule level

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used it like this in **main.ts** file:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
}
```

It works if your application is bootstrapped usig standalone component. If you use modules and try to implement standalone component within this architecture, you need to add same to providers of **app.module.ts**.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
})
```

Here are links from documentation that may be helpful

https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#bootstrapping-an-application-using-a-standalone-component

https://angular.io/guide/http#provide-the-interceptor

Comment: Angular v16, main.ts has `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule) .catch(err => console.error(err));`, not bootStrapped. Only way tested working is to add the `{ provide: ...}` to `providers` array in app.module.ts, not the lazy load module nor the component needs it. Side effect is every request goes through interceptor, adding overhead.

Answer (score 34):

As of version 15, Angular will be able to use provideHttpClient during bootstrapping of our application and functional interceptors:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
providers: [
    provideHttpClient(
        withInterceptors([authInterceptor]),
    ),
]
```

Funtional interceptor:

```
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from "@angular/common/http";

export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {

    req = req.clone({
        headers
    }

return next(req)
}
```

We need to add the withInterceptorsFromDi option to provideHttpClient if we can use a class-based interceptor:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
providers: [
    provideHttpClient(
        withInterceptorsFromDi(),
    ),
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AuthInterceptor,
        multi: true,
    },
 ] });
```

Comment: `withLegacyInterceptors()` does not exist anymore. For me `withInterceptorsFromDi()` worked

Comment: Thanks. It was my salvation. I wasted a lot of time to troubleshoot the problem.
Unfortunately on the Angular website the documentation is very sparse.

Comment: its `multi: true` and not `multiple: true` (see doc: https://angular.io/api/core/ClassProvider#properties) --- i would edit your post, but removing 3 chars doesnt cut it - min edit is 6 chars :)

Comment: with this new method - is it possible to include http interceptors from lazy-loaded modules?

Comment: FYI you can using withRequestsMadeViaParent()

Comment: thank you for this example.  Somehow they have made what worked simply  with classes to functions making configuration that much more confusing

Comment: To add to the answer above, you'll add the interceptor(s) to the `app.config.ts` file. Here is the link to define an interceptor in Angular 17:   https://angular.dev/guide/http/interceptors#defining-an-interceptor

Answer (score 0):

I had followed the steps given by other answers and blog but it still wasn't working for me.

In my case, the problem was that i had an additional import of HttpModule in my app.component.ts , like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    HttpClientModule, <---- here is the additional httpclient module import. This is breaking the interceptor.
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frontend';
}
```

So, i just removed the HTTPClientModule import from the app.component.ts as it's no longer needed since it's being provided in main.ts now.

Updated app component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
   ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frontend';
}
```

updated main.ts:

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));


import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { provideHttpClient, withInterceptors } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JWTInterceptor } from './jwt.interceptor';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),

    provideHttpClient(
      withInterceptors(
        [JWTInterceptor,]
      )
    )

  ]
};
```